# Dense subset of Hilbert space has trivial orthogonal complement

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

If $D$ is a dense subset (not subspace) of  a Hilbert space then is the orthogonal complement of $D$ equal to $\{ 0 \}$?

This is true if $D$ is a subspace but if you only know that $D$ is a subset you cannot apply the decomposition theorem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

Fix a vector $v$ in the orthogonal complement. The function $x\mapsto \langle x,v\rangle$ is continuous on the Hilbert space. Since it vanishes on a dense subset, it vanishes identically. In particular, it vanishes at $v$.

Comment: thanks, but i failed to explained that my problem is the inverse implication, that is, let's suppose that the ortogonal complement is {'0'} is it true that D is dense?.

Comment: The converse is false. Let D be the unit sphere, for example.

Comment: ok, thanks for you help